# How to retry succeeded job with bullmq

Tags: node.js, redis-cli, bullmq

I am trying to restart a job in bull mq with using only redis-cli.
The reason of not using JS api or just recreating a job is because redis is inside the k9s cluster on production and i basically unable to connect to it from outside. But i have console.

1. I've tried to find a job and it is okay, means we can work with it
   `HGETALL bull:DALENYS_NOTIFICATION_QUEUE:2445`
2. Then i've set it's status with this commands:
   `HSET bull:DALENYS_NOTIFICATION_QUEUE:2445 status waiting HDEL bull:DALENYS_NOTIFICATION_QUEUE:2445 finishedOn returnvalue`
   and this is also works good, but job is still in completed tab in bull dashboard
3. There are nothing in docs but some answers in google, which tells that i need to push the job id into wainitg queue and remove from completed like this
   `LPUSH bull:waiting:DALENYS_NOTIFICATION_QUEUE 2445 ZREM bull:completed:DALENYS_NOTIFICATION_QUEUE 2445`
   But the issue is that there are no keys like :waiting: or :completed: